# subset variable by matching strings in one column with strings in another variable

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a list of strings (compound names) in variable_1. I am using bash and trying to subset variable_2 by selecting the lines whose string in column 2 are an exact match to the strings in variable_1.  The result would contain the values from column 1 and 2 as shown in variable 3 below. I have many thousands of lines but example data shown below.

Any bash, grep, awk etc solutions? I cannot seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

echo "$variable_1":

```
Zeaxanthin
Zeaxanthin diglucoside
Zentinic
Zephyramine
(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
Zymosterol
Zymosterone
```

echo "$variable_2":

```
C00371 Zeatin
C06098 Zeaxanthin
C15969 Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C15984 Zeaxanthin diglucoside diester
C08590 Zeinoxanthin
C16075 (Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C05437 Zymosterol
C22136 Zymosterone
```

echo "$variable_3" (result)

```
C06098 Zeaxanthin
C15969 Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C16075 (Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C05437 Zymosterol
C22136 Zymosterone
```

Comment: Is Python an option?

Comment: Im doing it as part of a larger bash script but yes I can always do a part in python!

Comment: What data type are your variables? Single strings, consisting of a single, multiline text? Arrays of strings? Something else? And where are they? In shell variables? In files? Or where else?

Comment: They are multi-line so strings separated by newline char and both stored in shell variables

Comment: where did the data come from to populate these 2x variables? I would normally expect thousands of lines of data to be stored in a file, a database table or an array; or perhaps the data is the output from another process? loading all of these lines into a single variable is a bit odd (so I'm wondering if there's a point earlier in your processing where we have access to this data in a more suitable format).

Comment: do you need to maintain any specific ordering for the final result? and does the final result need to be stored in a single variable? (follow-on question would be how is `variable_3` going to be used later on?)

Answer (score 1):

I present one succinct, not much portable solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
gawk '
    NR==FNR{
        a[$0]++;next
    }
    {
        x=gensub(/^[^ ]* /,"",1)
        if (x in a) print
    }
' <(echo "$variable_1") <(echo "$variable_2")
```

And another a bit longer, but POSIX compliant:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$variable_1" > file1
echo "$variable_2" > file2

awk '
    NR==FNR{
        a[$0]++;next
    }
    {
        x=$0
        sub(/^[^ ]* /,"",x)
        if (x in a) print
    }
' file1 file2
```

As a last remark, I earnestly suggest you not to clump a bunch of lines in a variable. It just makes things harder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ordering of the final result set is not an issue, the `join` command comes to mind, except for a couple issues:

- can only join on a single field
- the input data must be sorted by the join field

We can get around this with a few sets of transformations ...

We'll start by looking at how this would be done if the data is in 2 files:

```
$ cat f1
Zeaxanthin
Zeaxanthin diglucoside
Zentinic
Zephyramine
(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
Zymosterol
Zymosterone

$ cat f2
C00371 Zeatin
C06098 Zeaxanthin
C15969 Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C15984 Zeaxanthin diglucoside diester
C08590 Zeinoxanthin
C16075 (Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C05437 Zymosterol
C22136 Zymosterone
```

By default `join` uses white space as the delimiter between fields; but since we want to include white space in our join 'field', we need to introduce a new delimiter (solely for the purpose of the `join` command). We can do this by introducing another character as a delimiter ... with the proviso that the character we use must not exist in the data files.

For the sake of this example we'll use a comma (`,`); for file `f1` we'll introduce a comma as the leading character, while for file `f2` we'll change the first space to a comma:

```
$ sed 's/^/,/' f1
,Zeaxanthin
,Zeaxanthin diglucoside
,Zentinic
,Zephyramine
,(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
,Zymosterol
,Zymosterone

$ sed 's/ /,/' f2
C00371,Zeatin
C06098,Zeaxanthin
C15969,Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C15984,Zeaxanthin diglucoside diester
C08590,Zeinoxanthin
C16075,(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C05437,Zymosterol
C22136,Zymosterone
```

At this point both data sets now have 2 fields (based on a delimiter of a comma).  Yes, field #1 for file `f1` is a null.

From a `join` perspective we plan on joining the 2 data sets based on field #2, but first we need to get the data sorted by field #2 ... which we can do with the `sort` command.

In both cases we'll sort the data sets by field #2 (using a comma as the delimiter):

```
$ sed 's/^/,/' f1 | sort -t, -k2
,(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
,Zeaxanthin
,Zeaxanthin diglucoside
,Zentinic
,Zephyramine
,Zymosterol
,Zymosterone

$ sed 's/ /,/' f2 | sort -t, -k2
C16075,(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C00371,Zeatin
C06098,Zeaxanthin
C15969,Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C15984,Zeaxanthin diglucoside diester
C08590,Zeinoxanthin
C05437,Zymosterol
C22136,Zymosterone
```

Now we're ready to pass these data sets to `join`:

```
$ join -j2 -t, -o1.1,1.2 <(sed 's/ /,/' f2 | sort -t, -k2) <(sed 's/^/,/' f1 | sort -t, -k2) 
C16075,(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C06098,Zeaxanthin
C15969,Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C05437,Zymosterol
C22136,Zymosterone
```

NOTE: The `-o1.1,1.2` says to only display fields #1 and #2 from the first data set.

All that's needed at this point is to strip out our comma; we can do this with another `sed` command:

```
$ join -j2 -t, -o1.1,1.2 <(sed 's/ /,/' f2 | sort -t, -k2) <(sed 's/^/,/' f1 | sort -t, -k2) | sed 's/,/ /'g
C16075 (Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C06098 Zeaxanthin
C15969 Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C05437 Zymosterol
C22136 Zymosterone
```

---

Now, to address the same data set but stored inside of 2x variables ...

```
$ echo "
++++++++++++++++++++
${variable_1}
++++++++++++++++++++
${variable_2}
++++++++++++++++++++
"
++++++++++++++++++++
Zeaxanthin
Zeaxanthin diglucoside
Zentinic
Zephyramine
(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
Zymosterol
Zymosterone
++++++++++++++++++++
C00371 Zeatin
C06098 Zeaxanthin
C15969 Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C15984 Zeaxanthin diglucoside diester
C08590 Zeinoxanthin
C16075 (Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C05437 Zymosterol
C22136 Zymosterone
++++++++++++++++++++
```

This should be (relatively) easy in that we just need to replace our file references with our variables, and for this example we'll pass the variables to the initial `sed` commands as here strings:

```
$ join -j2 -t, -o1.1,1.2 <(sed 's/ /,/' <<< "${variable_2}" | sort -t, -k2) <(sed 's/^/,/' <<< "${variable_1}" | sort -t, -k2) | sed 's/,/ /'
C16075 (Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C06098 Zeaxanthin
C15969 Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C05437 Zymosterol
C22136 Zymosterone
```

Answer (score 0):

I will let you worry about the difference between multiline strings stored as environment variables and multiline text files. I will show how you can take two multiline text files as inputs and get the desired result on standard output.

Important observation: Whenever we talk about `grep`, `sed` and `awk` we are always talking about regular expressions. We must pay attention to the meaning of special characters (possible metacharacters) in the inputs. For example, one of your inputs uses parentheses. Luckily, those are not metacharacters in BRE (basic regular expressions), so I didn't need to be too careful; but if, for example, your input strings may include dot, or asterisk, etc., you will have to pay some attention to this issue or you will get incorrect results.

So, here are the two files (with blank lines added for easier reading):

```
[mathguy@localhost ~/test]$ more f1

Zeaxanthin
Zeaxanthin diglucoside
Zentinic
Zephyramine
(Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
Zymosterol
Zymosterone

[mathguy@localhost ~/test]$ more f2

C00371 Zeatin
C06098 Zeaxanthin
C15969 Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C15984 Zeaxanthin diglucoside diester
C08590 Zeinoxanthin
C16075 (Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C05437 Zymosterol
C22136 Zymosterone
```

And here is a possible solution:

```
[mathguy@localhost ~/test]$ sed 's/^/[^ ]* /' f1 | grep -x -f - f2

C06098 Zeaxanthin
C15969 Zeaxanthin diglucoside
C16075 (Z)-Phenylacetaldehyde oxime
C05437 Zymosterol
C22136 Zymosterone
```

This assumes that a line in the second file must consist of zero or more non-space characters, followed by exactly one space, followed by a complete line from the first file. `sed` takes each line from the first file and prepends the characters `[^ ]*`(note that there is a space after asterisk - not easily seen with the naked eye). The output from `sed` is used as the "file" of regular expressions in the `grep` function (invoked via `-`). `grep` uses the `-x` flag to require an exact match of the entire line of text.

**EDIT** The OP in a comment (below) stated that some of the input strings do, in fact, contain characters that are metacharacters for BRE. Here is how that can be handled. The first pass through `sed` simply adds a backslash before every metacharacter in the strings from `f1`; then the rest is unchanged.

```
sed 's/[\.*^$[]/\\&/g' f1 | sed 's/^/[^ ]* /' | grep -x -f - f2
```

I hope I remember the BRE metacharacters correctly (backslash, period, asterisk, caret, dollar, and opening square bracket). If not, the list in the bracketed expression in the first `sed` should be modified as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I  got this error: grep: -:4152: Invalid range end. 
This is the line: Thiocarboxy-[sulfur-carrier protein] 
So I presume it is from the hard brackets. Unfortunately, many of my lines do have regex characters. How would you suggest getting around this?

Comment: @compy_comp_comp - By escaping the BRE metacharacters from the first file (in a preliminary sed pass) first. Let me add to the answer to show how